# Why doesn't my lightning component work in iOS?

Tags: lightning-apps

I have a functioning app that I can access via https://na16.lightning.force.com/one/one.app but when I log into the Salesforce1 app on an iPhone the tab is there but when I select it the app never shows up, just a white screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Version 6.x of the S1 native container broke Lightning Component Tab support - this is supposed to be fixed in the next major release of the container (7.x). I was not happy about this. Also be forewarned that the Android container still does not have Lightning Component Tab support - its on the backlog to be completed but I do not have an ETA on it yet.

Comment: Is there an ETA on 7.x for iPhone?  1 day,  1 week, or 1 month?

Comment: I am working on getting an ETA on this - expect I will not hear back from the product owner until tomorrow sometime though.

Comment: [Safe harbor of course] the product owner for this just got back to me and says "7.0 will be GA on iOS at the end of November."